# What are the optimal settings for `org.gradle.parallel.threads` and `org.gradle.workers.max`?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

The [official guide for optimizing Kotlin/Native compilation times](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-improving-compilation-time.html#gradle-configuration) suggests setting the Gradle property `org.gradle.parallel.threads`. But it doesn't give any details on how to decide on a number. Also, the official [Gradle Build Environment doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) doesn't even mention the `threads` setting. The Gradle doc does mentions `org.gradle.workers.max`, but the Kotlin docs doesn't mention the `max` setting.

The lack of mention of both properties on either doc raises questions:

- how do these to properties interact (how many threads/worker or worker/thread are there)
- are both of these properties meant to be configured or is one supposed to replace the other?
- How should one determine the optimal values for both properties?